# Tkinter image blank (without PIL)

Tags: python, image, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am making an animated presentation and I want to add an image to it, but I can't use PIL because it will be presented at school, where PIL isn't installed, so I used the method given by the website http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm, but it doesn't work - my slide is still blank. What should I do?

Here is my code (copied almost completely from the website - did I miss something out?):

```py
photo = PhotoImage('Alveoli.png')
label = Label(image=photo)
label.image = photo # keep a reference!
label.pack()
```

Comment: What is the code leading to that problem? We can't answer you if you just state your problem and not what you tried or have done first.

Comment: You can't open `.png` files with PhotoImage. 
`The PhotoImage class can read GIF and PGM/PPM images from files`

Comment: @Python IT How do I open PNGs then? I don't have any code that's related to the image if that's what you mean.

Comment: Effbot https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm suggests PIL. But since PIL isn't available to you I would recommend Converting the image ;)

Comment: Open the file with an image editing software and export is as `PGM`

Comment: @Python IT OK. I did it (in PPM when I realised PGM was gray), but it still doesn't work - the window is blank.

Comment: I don't have a reference handy, but I think that there is support for `.png` in the current versions of tkinter.

Comment: @bobbyta74: since tkinter 8.6 is `.png` is supported. Could it be that the image didn't show because you didn't add your `root` application as `root` to the `Label`?

Comment: @PythonIT I think either that or I didn't include `file =` in `photo = PhotoImage(file="img.ppm")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not open `.png` files without using an external image library. Since `PIL` isn't available I'd think other similar libraries aren't either.

**EDIT:** Note: `PNG` files are supported for `tkinter v8.6+`.

The only possibility that comes to mind is converting the image to another, compatible format like `GIF` or `PGM`

If you have the image in one of those formats you can simply add them. It worked just fine for me with this code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

photo = PhotoImage(file="img.ppm")

img = Label(root, image=photo)
img.image = photo
img.place(x=0, y=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @bobbyta74 `PhotoImage.zoom()` should be what you need.

Comment: Is there a command for layering widgets? I want to put shapes 'on top' of the image ('in front'? I don't know how to phrase it) so that I see them, because right now they're hidden behind it.

Comment: @bobbyta74 `img.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=0, relheight=0)` should be good for that.`place()` can place images on a certain point on the main window. You can `pack()` or `grid()` the other widgets just fine.

Comment: The img disappeared for some reason when I used `img.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=0, relheight=0)`.

Comment: use `1` for `relwidth` and `relheight`, sorry. These two options scale the Widget according to the main frame from 0 to 1.

Comment: It did bring the img back, but I still can't see the shape

Comment: I tried `relwidth = 2` and `relheight = 2` for the shape, but it doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201416/discussion-between-bobbyta74-and-python-it).